# django_jsonforms are not displayed in the browser

Tags: python, json, django, django-forms, jsonforms

I want to run a ready python project in virtual environment. When I run the project I face no error. And when I write this in the terminal "py manage.py runserver" , I can see just a label of the project in the browser and forms are not being shown. I searched a lot, this project is almost complete and is working in other systems. I don't know what changes I should apply to the project.

Comment: Can you share a link with us for this almost-ready project?

Comment: It is a project from a compony and I am not allowed to share the code, unfortunately.

Comment: When I run the project in Terminal I can see some results in "Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/". There are 3 versions for the project, then after selecting one of them, just a label is available and django and .json forms are not shown in the browser. I searched for it a lot but did not find a solution.

Comment: Without sharing your code i can't help you, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

By using this setting I could solve the problem.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
# STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
# STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
DEBUG = True
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem.

Because I had not executed the `python manage.py collectstatic` command after installing django_jsonform, the form that should have been displayed by django_jsonform was not displayed.

After activating the virtualenv, run the `python manage.py collectstatic` command.